# Window resize function stops working on resize

Tags: jquery, html, aspect-ratio

I'm using the following jQuery script to keep my aspect ratio of a div on different window sizes.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
var ratio = 0.53;
$('.uitgelicht-item').width($(window).width() * ratio).height($(window).height() * ratio);
// instead of directly using "$(window).width() * ratio", you can call a method to
// calculate width and height each time window is resized.

});
```

It works when I load the page, but as soon as I resize my window (or turn mobile / tablet screen) The ratio is lost.

How do I get this script to stay active when my window resizes?

Comment: Why not just use pure css for this, would be much cleaner?

Comment: This resize event should always work but you may want to be aware that some devices (you mention mobile and tablet) do indeed return the "wrong" width or height based on orientation and thus may be why your dimensions are not changing. This is a long and lengthy read but worthwhile: http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/

Comment: I'm using 3 floating divs:
.uitgelicht-item {
width: 30%;
overflow: hidden;
margin-right: 2%;
background: #FFF;
padding: 3px;
float: left;
}
Could this be te problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your script stays active on window resize. Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WFXR/) I am unable to reproduce the issue you are saying.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
var ratio = 0.53, div = $('.uitgelicht-item');

div.width($(window).width() * ratio).height($(window).height() * ratio);
div.text('width = ' + div.width() + ',height = ' + div.height())
// instead of directly using "$(window).width() * ratio", you can call a method to
// calculate width and height each time window is resized.

});
```

Comment: Script is working indeed, turned out i did not need it.

On load my css was good, but when resizing $(window).resize(function() script started working, and messed things up again. I added this script a few weeks ago. Dont know why i thought i needed it but i feel pretty stupid now.

Sorry and thanks for your input